# i would like an error check to ensure that the string has vowels input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
from collections import Counter
Astring = input("Enter a word or sentence: ")
vowel = 'a' 'e' 'i' 'o' 'u'
Astring = Counter(c for c in Astring.lower() if c in vowel)
min_values = {mainv: Astring[mainv] for mainv in Astring if Astring[mainv] == min(Astring.values())}

if vowel not in Astring:
    print ("your text must contain vowels")

else:


    print("The least occuring vowel is:")
    for m in min_values:
        print("{vowel} with {occ} occurences.".format(vowel=m, occ=min_values[m]))
```

I would like my code to output the lowest occurring vowel on top of this i would like an error check to ensure that the string has vowels input in to it

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I want to have an error check to ensure that the input does contain vowels

Comment: That's not a problem, but a goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of issues with formatting and syntax in you example, but the following works and is reasonably close to how you were attempting to do it:

```
from collections import Counter

VOWELS = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

string = raw_input("Enter a word or sentence: ")
if not any(True for vowel in VOWELS if vowel in string.lower()):
    print("your text must contain vowels")
else:
    print("The least occuring vowel is: {}".format(Counter(c for c in string.lower() if c in VOWELS).most_common()[-1]))
```